# Extjs4, How to update window bbar(toolbar)?

Tags: extjs4

I want to update Extjs window bbar(toolbar) dynamically, but I don't know how should I make it work,

Example Code :

```
var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    modal: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
    // panel
    },
    bbar: ['->', {
    xtype: 'buttongroup',
    items: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function () {
        invoicingWin.destroy();
        }
    }]
    }, {
    xtype: 'buttongroup',
    items: [{
        text: 'Continue',
        handler: function () {

        var test = new Ext.Toolbar({
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: ['->', { html: "Close"}]
        });

        //  !! I want to replace this window bbar to test(toolbar)

        } // btn handler
    }]// items
    }]
}).show();
```

Anybody know, please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you want? You want to replace the bbar with a toolbar when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's good solution. but it will work.

```
var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    modal: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    width:400,
    height:400,
    items: {
    // panel
    },
    bbar: ['->', { 
    xtype: 'buttongroup',
    items: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function () {
        invoicingWin.destroy();
        }
    }]
    }, {
    xtype: 'buttongroup',
    items: [{
        text: 'Continue',
        handler: function () {

        var test = new Ext.Toolbar({
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: ['->', { html: "Close"}]
        });
        myWin.removeDocked(myWin.down('toolbar'));
        myWin.addDocked(test);
        //  !! I want to replace this window bbar to test(toolbar)

        } // btn handler
    }]// items
    }]
}).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, ExtJS does not expect to replace the toolbar of panel (and descendants of panel). Normally, the toolbar will have list of items needed and you only hide/show them.

Actually you still can use `getDockedItems()`, `getDockedComponent()`, `addDocked()`, `insertDocked()`, `removeDocked()` to fulfill your needs.